# Array variable in an ember controller

Tags: javascript, ember.js

-I'm kind of new to ember js and javascript in general and I can't seem to figure out why my methods keep spitting out the error that both `taskData` and `personData` are undefined. Any feedback is appreciated!

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({

    taskData: [],
    personData: [],



      actions: {

          taskData: [],
          personData: [],

        saveTask() {

            var task = this.get("task");
            taskData.push(task);
        },

        savePerson()
        {
            var person = this.get("person");
            personData.push(person);
        },

        print(){

            alert(taskData);
            alert(personData);
        }

      }

});
```

Comment: Putting `taskData` and `personData` inside the actions hash is not going to do anything useful. Remove them. Then you need to refer to them with `this.get('taskData')`. etc. Also, use `pushObject` instead of `push`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Object keys `taskData` and `personData` are not variables, but keys of an object which is then passed as an argument to the `extend` function. You need to use `this` keyword.

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({

    taskData: [],
    personData: [],



      actions: {

          taskData: [],
          personData: [],

        saveTask() {

            var task = this.get("task");
            this.taskData.push(task);
        },

        savePerson()
        {
            var person = this.get("person");
            this.personData.push(person);
        },

        print(){

            alert(this.taskData);
            alert(this.personData);
        }

      }

});
```

Comment: But (a) you didn't add `this` everywhere it's needed, and (b) you did not remove the unnecessary `taskData` etc. from inside the actions hash.

Comment: No, you need `this.get('taskData')` etc.

Comment: @torazaburo. I think it is gong to work fine this way too.

Comment: @jvangore31 This answer is not ember way..  until this implements what torazaburo suggested.